# Select job as parameter in Jenkins (Declarative) Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to set a parameter in Jenkins Declarative Pipeline enabling the user to select one of the jobs defined on Jenkins. Something like:

```
parameters {
        choice(choices: getJenkinsJobs())
    }
```

How can this be achieved?

Background info: I would like to implement a generic manual promotion job with the Pipeline, where the user would select a build number and the job name and the job would get promoted. 
I dislike the idea of using the `input` step as it prevents the job from completing and I can't get e.g. the junit reports on tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over all existing `hudson.model.Job` instances and get their names. The following should work

```
@NonCPS
def getJenkinsJobs() {
    Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(hudson.model.Job)*.fullName.join('\n')
}

pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        choice(choices: getJenkinsJobs(), name: 'JOB')
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Accepted, but two issues here: 1) using Jenkins.instance results in a warning that this is a security vulnerability 2) you should probably pass a '\n'-separated String to the choices parameter, not an array. Otherwise works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: @KamilRoman, can't do anything about 1 point but you have to approve this only once. You are right about 2, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin

and use basic groovy script as a input.

Refer the below URL for how to list the build/jobs.
https://themettlemonkey.wordpress.com/2013/01/29/jenkins-build-number-drop-down/